# Using laravel, how can I display a HTML class called 'products' in a 3x3 grid view whilst also connecting to the database to obtain the products

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I'm using laravel to display information about products that people are selling on the home page. Each product contains a small image and other attributes. At the moment each product listed is on an new row meaning a user has to scroll all the way up and down to view them. How can I display it in a 3x3 grid?

Comment: set the css atrributes of said class.. `float: left; width:33.3%` may need to adjust padding and margins to make it fit, could even lower the width a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly copy of :

[Display 3 items per row - while loop - php/mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385165/display-3-items-per-row-while-loop-php-mysql)

[Loop row in bootstrap every 3 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561301/loop-row-in-bootstrap-every-3-columns)

Look into links above, will gonna help you.